# Compiling error: Return type for the method is missing

Tags: java

```
public class StoreRatioNumberClass
{
 private int num;
 private int den;

public RationalNumber() //here
{
  num = 0;
  den = 1;
}
public RationalNumber(int newNum, int newDen) //and here, but it gives me 3 separate errors for it//
{
   num = newNum;
   den = newDen;
   simplify();
}
private void simplify()
{
  int gcd = gcd();
  finalNum = num/gcd;
  finalDen = den/gcd;
}


private static int gcd(int a, int b) 
{
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return gcd(b, a % b);

}

public double getValue()
{
  return (double)num/den;
}

public String toString()
{
  return(num + "/" + den);
}

}
```

My question is how do I solve this compiling issue on lines 7 & 11? This class takes the numerators and denominators entered in the main method class not shown here and simplifies the rational number with the GCD. Also, when I do put in a return type it just comes up with even more errors and warnings so I'm stumped! Thank you for looking and all of your inputs.

Comment: Your class is called `StoreRatioNumberClass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the name of your class in constructor:

```
public StoreRatioNumberClass(int newNum, int newDen) {
       //...
```

otherwise compiler will think you are about to declare a method and is confused about the missing return type obviously

Answer (score 3):

You named your class *StoreRatioNumberClass*, as in the following class declaration

```
public class StoreRatioNumberClass
```

I believe you were trying to define constructors for this class, in the lines the compiler complains. Constructors must have the same name as the class, otherwise, they're interpreted as method names (such as your `simplify`). However, these false method definitions miss their return type.

Change

```
public RationalNumber() //here
```

to

```
public StoreRatioNumberClass() //here
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `RationalNumber` methods don't declare a return type.  The form you're using is only allowed for constructors.  If you change the name of both methods to `StoreRatioNumberClass` (i.e., make the method names match the class name to make them valid constructors), your compiler errors should go away.